# Rails 5, Route declare but not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my routes config i have:

```
constraints subdomain: 'api' do
    scope module: 'api' do
        namespace :v1 do
            get '/me', to: 'users#me'
        end
    end
end
```

bin/rake routes return

```
v1_me GET    /v1/me(.:format)     api/v1/users#me {:subdomain=>"api"}
```

When i try the uri http://localhost:3000/v1/me, http://localhost:3000/api/v1/me or http://localhost:3000/me with postman i have a 404 not found error.

```
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/v1/me"):
```

What is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a constraint set for subdomain. 
So you'll have to access it via something like `api.localhost:3000`
Which won't work out of the box for any dev env.

Your routes makes sure that the specified endpoint is only defined for the `api` subdomain.

You can try these:

`http://api.lvh.me:3000`

`http://api.localhost:3000`

You might need to add entries in your hosts file to point any custom domain to `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subdomain to access localhost, like this `http://api.lvh.me:3000/`

So your URL becomes `http://api.lvh.me:3000/api/v1/me`